# Hadoop daemons can't stop using proper command

Tags: linux, hadoop

Running Hadoop system would run some daemon jobs like namenode, journalnode, etc. I will use namenode as an example.

When we start namenode we can use command: hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode

When we stop namenode we can use command: hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode.

But here comes the question, if I just start the namenode yesterday or couple of hours ago, the stop command would work fine. But if the namenode has been working for say 1 month. When I am using the stop command, it will show:

no namenode to stop.

But I can see the daemon NameNode running using command JPS. Then I have to use the kill command to kill the process.

Why would this happen? Any way to make sure the stop command can always work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why hadoop-daemon.sh is not working after some time is because in hadoop-env.sh there are parameters called: 
export HADOOP_PID_DIR
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR
which stored pid number of those daemons. The default location of that directory is /tmp. The problem is /tmp folder will be automatically cleaned up after sometime(Red Hat Linux). In this case the pid file is deleted, so
when we run the daemon command, the command can't find the process id stored in the that file.
The same reson with yarn-daemon.sh command.

Modify hadoop-env.sh:
HADOOP_PID_DIR
HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR
yarn-env.sh:
YARN_PID_DIR
mapred-env.sh:
HADOOP_MAPRED_PID_DIR
to other directories instead of using default /tmp folder should solve the problem.
After modification, restart all the processes related to that.
Also for security concern, folder contains pid should not be able to be accessed by other non-admin users.

Comment: how can i stop hadoop?